# Illegal Group function SQL

Tags: mysql

I am working on this task where I need to calculate the CGPA for each student, along with the formula of Grades*credits/total credits.

```
select 
    round(sum((grade.grade*course.credits)/count(course.courseno)),1), 
    student.studentNo
from 
    course, grade, student, offering
where 
    student.studentno = grade.studentno
    and course.courseno = offering.courseno
    and offering.offerno = grade.offerno
group by
    student.studentNo;
```

I'm sort of stuck an unable to proceed as i don't know what's wrong with this.

EDIT: so i made a few changes as you guys pointed out but im still in trouble

```
select grade.studentno, 
(select sum (t)
from(select(grade*credits)/count(offering.courseno)
    from student s2, grade g2, offering o2, course c2
    where s2.studentno=g2.studentno
    and g2.offerno=o2.offerno
    and o2.courseno=c2.courseno
    group by g2.studentno
    ) t
)
from student, grade, offering, course
where student.studentno=grade.studentno
and grade.offerno=offering.offerno
and offering.courseno=course.courseno
group by grade.studentno;
```

Error

> Code 1054: Unknown column offering.courseno in 'field list'

It does not recognize the aggregation in the subquery for 'count'

Comment: Cann't you just use `AVG(grade.grade * course.credits)`?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Nesting aggregate functions in the same SELECT, such as `SUM(X/COUNT(Y))`, is not allowed. When nesting is needed, you can use a subquery to do one and then the outer query to perform the other; which is often necessary anyway, as such scenarios usually call for different grouping criteria.

Comment: Okay so i tried to make some changes, but it's still not working:

    select grade.studentno, 
 (select sum (t)
 from(select(grade*credits)/count(offering.courseno)
  from student s2, grade g2, offering o2, course c2
  where s2.studentno=g2.studentno
  and g2.offerno=o2.offerno
  and o2.courseno=c2.courseno
  group by g2.studentno
  ) t
    )
    from student, grade, offering, course
    where student.studentno=grade.studentno
    and grade.offerno=offering.offerno
    and offering.courseno=course.courseno
     group by grade.studentno;

Answer (score 0):

Nesting aggregate functions in the same SELECT is not allowed except for [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode. You can use a subquery to select both columns similar to this

```
    select round(sum((grade.grade*course.credits)/count(course.courseno)),1) from  (select student.studentNo from course, grade, student, offering where student.studentno=grade.studentno and course.courseno=offering.courseno and offering.offerno=grade.offerno) group by student.studentNo;
```